# Leaflet export to jpg

Tags: leaflet, export, jpg

Does anybody know if there is a way to export the current view of a Leaflet map to jpg?  The setup is as follows:

Leaflet is hooked up to an Oracle database. Depending on user interaction, various Geojson layers are displayed.  I'd like to include a way for the user to export the current view to a static file (jpg or png).  The static file should include the basemap.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can achieve this by rendering the view with a permalink in PhantomJS.

Comment: Rendering using phantomjs is not perfect I couldn't find a way of stet mining when the page is fully loaded all visible tiles and markers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is now a plugin for Leaflet that handles this.

[Leaflet.print](https://github.com/aratcliffe/Leaflet.print)

Answer (score 3):

Another plugin [leaflet-image](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-image)

The plugin is working well with standard markers, for export leaflet map with special markers you can see [export-leaflet-map-to-image](https://orenw.wordpress.com/2015/06/07/export-leaflet-map-to-image/)